# JQuery/Javascript only execute the first condition (In a visualforce page with apex:outputpanel)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, visualforce

I'm quite new in Jquery as I was use to only javascript.

I'm trying to execute a jquery function but it only execute the first condition in the code (the first IF). The second one (the second IF) is never executed. I must have something wrong and I apologise if something to obvious. The next code is Jquery function that is embeed into a visualforce page (that's why the syntax of the componenent's Id).

```
$(function() {
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' });
$( "#datepicker2" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' });
if(document.getElementById('{!$Component.mainform.inputDATE}').value != null){
    var obj = document.getElementById('{!$Component.mainform.inputDATE}').value;
    $( "#datepicker" ).val(obj);
    alert("obj: "+obj);
}
if(document.getElementById('{!$Component.mainform.inputDATE2}').value != null){
    var obj2 = document.getElementById('{!$Component.mainform.inputDATE2}').value;
    $( "#datepicker2" ).val(obj2);
    alert("obj2: "+obj2);
}    
});
```

Any advice will be very appreciated it. I tested in different ways but only the first condition is executed.

Comment: Could you provide a jsFiddle with your relevant HTML and (maybe) CSS?

Comment: did you check the console for errors? debugging javascript on chrome is pretty simple

Comment: The code does not have visible syntax errors. Are you sure that the second condition gives positive result?

Comment: The .value of an input will never be null - it could be an empty string, but `"" ! = null`. (I don't think that is *the* problem, but it's certainly *a* problem.)

Comment: If the element doesn't exist, calling `.value` on it will throw an error. Are you sure that an element with that ID exists on the page?

Comment: Thanks for your opinion guys. I found what was the problem. There is nothing wrong with the code. The problem is that I have inputDATE in section of a visualforce page that it will be visible according to one condition and the other inputDATE2 in other condtiion. Hence at the top function does not recognized those values like they if one of those never exist. I will post the code to explain in a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the comments I found that there is no problem with the jquery function. The problem was related to actually, visualforce. In a visualforce page I can divide it into sections and rendered if according to certain function. Example:

```
 <apex:outputpanel rendered="{!objOrder.Id!=''}"  >   
   <apex:inputHidden id="inputDATE" value=" {!objOrder.Required_Date__c}" />           
   <input type="text" id="datepicker"/>
 </apex:outputpanel>

 <apex:outputpanel rendered="{!objOrder.Id==''}"  >   
   <apex:inputHidden id="inputDATE2" value=" {!objOrder.Required_Date__c}" />           
   <input type="text" id="datepicker2"/>
 </apex:outputpanel>
```

So, I'm assuming that the Jquery function at the top of the page does not recognise if one of those input will be rendered or not and that's it never works the second condition (the first condition is the more common)

```
$(function() {
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' });
$( "#datepicker2" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' });
if(document.getElementById('{!$Component.mainform.inputDATE}').value != null){
   var obj = document.getElementById('{!$Component.mainform.inputDATE}').value;
   $( "#datepicker" ).val(obj);
   alert("obj: "+obj);
}
if(document.getElementById('{!$Component.mainform.inputDATE2}').value != null){
   var obj2 = document.getElementById('{!$Component.mainform.inputDATE2}').value;
   $( "#datepicker2" ).val(obj2);
   alert("obj2: "+obj2);
}    
});
```

So what I did and apologise if not follow the best practices, was divide the jquery function into two parts and embeed into the section that belongs. In that way it will execute both functions. The final code is this one:

```
 <apex:outputpanel rendered="{!objOrder.Id!=''}"  >   
   <apex:inputHidden id="inputDATE" value=" {!objOrder.Required_Date__c}" />           
   <input type="text" id="datepicker"/>
   <script>
$(function() {
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' });
if(document.getElementById('{!$Component.mainform.inputDATE}').value != null){
   var obj = document.getElementById('{!$Component.mainform.inputDATE}').value;
   $( "#datepicker" ).val(obj);
   alert("obj: "+obj);
}
}); 
   </script>
 </apex:outputpanel>

 <apex:outputpanel rendered="{!objOrder.Id==''}"  >   
   <apex:inputHidden id="inputDATE2" value=" {!objOrder.Required_Date__c}" />           
   <input type="text" id="datepicker2"/>
   <script>
   $(function() {
   $( "#datepicker2" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' });
   if(document.getElementById('{!$Component.mainform.inputDATE2}').value != null){
   var obj2 = document.getElementById('{!$Component.mainform.inputDATE2}').value;
   $( "#datepicker2" ).val(obj2);
   alert("obj2: "+obj2);
}    
}); 
   </script>
 </apex:outputpanel>
```

I hope this could help someone in the future facing issues between salesforce rendered and jquery.

Thanks for the help...!!!